Informing the Code Analyzer about Non-nullable Properties in Returned Objects
Is there a way to inform the code analyzer that a nullable property of a returned object is not null, particularly when the object is created by a different class? For example, consider the following scenario:
class Foo {
  public string? Name { get;set; }
}

class Bar {

  // what attribute to use here?
  Foo CreateFoo() {
    return new Foo { Name = "123" };
  }
}

Is there an attribute that can be used to indicate to the code analyzer that any Foo object created by Bar.CreateFoo() will always have a non-null Foo.Name property?

No, because there's nothing about the type or its members that tells the compiler it's not null. Nullable analyis depends on signatures and attributes, and you can't apply attributes to specific instances.
